# Specifying the fields to send on an 'update' command using the Kendo UI Framework Data Source

Tags: kendo-ui, sharepoint-2013

I am using the **Data Source** object to connect to a SharePoint 2013 ODATA source using REST and then use this as the data for a **Kendo UI Grid**.

The **Data Source** reads the list correctly and populates the grid, but when I update an item in the **Kendo UI Grid** the following error is returned by the REST end point.

> The property '__deferred' does not exist on type 'SP.SecurableObject'.
>   Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

This is caused by the **Data Source** returning all the properties from the initial read request and then returning in the update command.

SharePoint returns __deferred properties with a REST URL to defer loading, but is throwing a wobbly if they are returned back in an update command request.

Below is my **Data Source**

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: listUrl,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                }
            },
            create: {
                url: listUrl,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                }
            },
            update: {
                url: function (data) {
                    return listUrl + "(" + data.ID + ")";
                },
                beforeSend: function (jqXhr, options) {

                    var data = JSON.parse(options.data);

                    jqXhr.setRequestHeader("If-Match", data.__metadata.etag);

                },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
                },
            },
            destroy: {
                url: function (data) {
                    return listUrl + "(" + data.ID + ")";
                },
                type: "DELETE",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                    "If-Match": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            data: "d.results",
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    ID: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                    Title: { validation: { required: true } },
                    Body1: { validation: { required: true } },
                    Votes: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a "parameterMap" function on the DataSource.transport, and filter out the data you don't want.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  type: "odata",
  transport: {

    parameterMap: function(data, type){
      if (type === "update" && data["__deferred"]){
        delete data["__deferred"];
      }
      return kendo.stringify(data);
    }

    // ...
  },

  // ...
});
```

See http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap

Another option, if you're working with observable objects, is to provide a custom `.toJSON` method on  your object. I wrote up a blog post about this, here: http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-04-04/hijacking-tojson-for-fun-and-profit.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using Derick Bailey's answer I was able to do the following with the parameterMap

the question object is a defined data model. Using this method, it will only send over the fields defined in the model plus the __metadata field that is need by SharePoint.

```
parameterMap: function (data, type) {

                if (type == "update") {
                    for (var property in data) {
                        if (property != "__metadata" && !question.fields[property])
                            delete data[property];
                    }
                }

                return kendo.stringify(data);
            }
```